# how to select top association rules

Tags: database, associations, data-mining, solver

given rules are sorted in descending order of their lift ratio's and greater than 1.
Top 3 rules are needed from below.

Antecedants -- Consequents 
A,B -- C,D 
A -- C,D 
A,C -- B,D 
C,D -- A,B

Should I consider the top 3 rules straight away?

Comment: Why not *consider* them?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: As mentioned by Manish in below comments I believe if A,B -- C,D is having high confidence rate then A -- C,D & B -- C,D will also have high confidence rate..Even then do we need to consider second rule??

Comment: As explained below, what Manish said does not hold. Furthermore, A->CD can have much higher support, and thus be useful nevertheless. Assuming that you have 1% szpport for AB->CD, then a "weaker" rule A->CD if it applies to 99% of your data can be very interesting.

Answer (score -1):

If A,b -- c,d is a association rule then 
A -- c,d and b -- c,d will obviously have more confidence.So I dont think we need to consider 2nd rule.Correct me if my approach is wrong

Comment: No: If we have ABCD 5 times, but 10 times A alone, 10 times B alone, then the confidence of AB->CD is 100% A->CD has confidence 20%. Furthermore, lift != confidence.